# How to quit scala 2.11.0 REPL?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

In the last version of scala (2.10.3) REPL, I can type `exit` to quit from REPL.  However, in Scala 2.11.0 this doesn't work.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> exit
<console>:8: error: not found: value exit
              exit
              ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 270, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on upgrade, just use colon q.

```
:q
```

Additionally, `exit` was deprecated in 2.10.x with `sys.exit` suggested instead, so this works as well:

```
sys.exit
```

As a side note, I think they did this so you can distinguish between exiting the scala console in sbt and exiting sbt itself, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 44):

You options to leave the REPL as stated in the answers before are:

```
:quit
:q

Ctrl + d // Unix
Ctrl + z // Windows

sys.exit
```

Comment: Have no windows machine at my disposal right now. @GovindSinghNagarkoti . What works for you ?

Comment: @AndreasNeumann all others works for me except `ctrl+d` , i am using `windows 7`

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and have Cygwin installed: `ctrl+d` works but `ctrl+z` does not. Not sure if that's related to Cygwin or not.

Comment: ctrl-c also exits the repl, which is annoying because in literally every other repl it cancels the current line

Answer (score 14):

Use the end of file characters. `Ctrl-D` on linux, `Ctrl-Z` on Windows.

Using the `:help` command on my 2.10.3 REPL gets me this hint:

```
:quit        exit the interpreter
```

I don't know whether `:quit` is still there in 2.11.0 or not though.

Comment: If you use sbt, ctl-D will get you out of either command prompt. That's what I started doing at some point. The :q vs exit thing just drove me nuts. Can you tell?

Comment: You can also use `java.lang.System.exit(0);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  sure, i feel like typing that every time

Answer (score 4):

When I use `exit` in 2.10.4, I got a warning:

> warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details

You can use:

```
:q
:quit
sys.exit
```

all of them work in 2.11.x.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 
sys.exit 
OR 
:q
to exit the shell

Comment: This has already been pointed out, years ago, in the previous answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For sbt 1.4.1 commands use below command

```
 exit:Terminates the remote client or the build when called from the console.
 shutdown:Terminates the build.
```

Example

```
vudikeri@C02CP3LAMD6M scala % sbt version 
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.1 (N/A Java 14.0.1)

sbt:scala> shutdown
[info] shutting down sbt server
vudikeri@C02CP3LAMD6M scala % 

sbt:scala> exit
[info] shutting down sbt server
```